# Nodejs html pass argument inside img or link source

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

First of all I am new in NodeJS. I am trying to phrase arguments inside links and image source but its not working.

```
> <!-- template.html --> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
> href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> <div
> class="container" id="app">
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
>             <h1>Search</h1>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
>             <form action="" class="search-form">
>                 <div class="form-group has-feedback">
>                     <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
>                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search" v-model="query" >
>                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
>                 </div>
>             </form>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-md-3" v-for="result in results">
>             <div class="panel panel-default">
>                 <div class="panel-heading">
>                 <!-- display the city name and country  -->       <b>TIME:</b> {{ result._source.frametime }}, <b>FROM:</b> {{
> result._source.sourceip }} , <img id="link2">
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="panel-body">
>                 <!-- display the latitude and longitude of the city  -->      <p><b>Destination IP</b>: {{ result._source.destip }}, <b>Destination PORT</b>: {{ result._source.destporttcp }}  </p>      </br>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div> </div> <!--- some styling for the page --> <style>
>     .search-form .form-group {
>         float: right !important;
>         transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
>         width: 32px;
>         height: 32px;
>         background-color: #fff;
>         box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
>         border-radius: 25px;
>         border: 1px solid #ccc;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group input.form-control {
>         padding-right: 20px;
>         border: 0 none;
>         background: transparent;
>         box-shadow: none;
>         display: block;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
>         display: none;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
>         /* Firefox 18- */
>         display: none;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
>         /* Firefox 19+ */
>         display: none;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
>         display: none;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group:hover,
>     .search-form .form-group.hover {
>         width: 100%;
>         border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
>     }
> 
>     .search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
>         position: absolute;
>         top: -1px;
>         right: -2px;
>         z-index: 2;
>         display: block;
>         width: 34px;
>         height: 34px;
>         line-height: 34px;
>         text-align: center;
>         color: #3596e0;
>         left: initial;
>         font-size: 14px;
>     } </style>
> 
>   <script> var app = new Vue({
>     el: '#app',
>     // declare the data for the component (An array that houses the results and a query that holds the current search string)
>     data: {
>         results: [],
>         query: ''
>     },
>     // declare methods in this Vue component. here only one method which performs the search is defined
>     methods: {
>         // make an axios request to the server with the current search query
>         search: function() {
>             axios.get("http://192.168.100.244:3001/search?q=" + this.query)
>       //var strLink = "http://192.168.100.244/images/" + this.query;
>       //document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href",strLink);
>                 .then(response => {
>                     this.results = response.data;
> 
>                 })
>         }
>     },
>     // declare Vue watchers
>     watch: {
>         // watch for change in the query string and recall the search method
>         query: function() {
>             this.search();
>         }
>     }
> 
> })
> 
> 
>   </script>
```

This is my template.html file. I can able to place values from result but when i place argument inside img or link it is not passing through.

Eg: If `result._source.url`

contains (google.com)  , I need to use like `<a href=http://{{result._source.url}}></a>`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

let's try

```
<a href=`http://${result._source.url}`></a>
```

if you need pass args :

```
const http = `${URL}/?ret=${URL_ARGS}`;
...
...
<a href={http}>
```

rgds

Comment: which error ? I copied/pasted my code who is working fine